# errno: -4094 display after run "yarn dev"

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, yarnpkg-v2

```
 [Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, readlink 'C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\sih-project\project-showcase-client\.next\app-build-manifest.json'] {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'readlink',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\HP\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\sih-project\\project-showcase-client\\.next\\app-build-manifest.json'
}
```

for solving this error i deleted the .next folder by this "Remove-Item -Path .next -Recurse -Force" command. but after delete .next folder when i run "yarn dev", the following error occurs :

```
$ next dev
  ▲ Next.js 13.5.2
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000
  - Environments: .env.local

 ✓ Ready in 4.1s
 ⨯ src\app\page.tsx
page.tsx doesn't have a root layout. To fix this error, make sure every page has a root layout.
 ○ compiling /page ...
 ⨯ src\app\page.tsx
page.tsx doesn't have a root layout. To fix this error, make sure every page has a root layout.
 ⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.
```

i can not understand what is the problem please give me the solution...